# Converting a JavaScript file with Babel for use in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I have a JavaScript file `mystuff.js` which throws errors in IE11 (due to for..of loops, etc).

So I try to convert it with Babel for use in IE11. However the output from Babel does not seem to be IE11-compatible. (IE complains "*SCRIPT5009: 'require' is undefined*".)

It looks like the result of Babel is not really JavaScript for IE11...

---

For reference here the steps I did:

1. I install

   ```
    yarn add -D @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
    yarn add @babel/polyfill
   ```
2. I create a `babel.config.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "edge": "17",
          "firefox": "60",
          "chrome": "67",
          "safari": "11.1",
            "ie": "11"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3.6.4",
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

2. I have my JavaScript file in `src` so I run

   ```
    yarn babel src --out-dir lib
   ```
3. I create a new HTML file from my old HTML file so that it loads the JavaScript from  `lib` instead of `src`:

   ```
    <div id = "info">...</div>
    <script src="./lib/mystuff.js"></script>
   ```
4. I serve and view the HTMLfile in IE11, but get the aforementioned error in IE's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"require" is commonjs module import function and is not available in browsers api (only nodejs) , you can use attribute type='module' on script tag AND ES6 module imports but it only works in newer browsers.
Otherwise if you use imports in source code and want to ship the code to older browsers you need to use bundlers such as webpack, rollup, or parcel( way easier to setup than webpack ), Babel only polyfills javascript but does not bundles modules.

You also need to make sure babel does not transforms ES6 modules to commonjs modules (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules) because commonjs is not supported in browsers as i said before

Comment: So does this mean that _after_ I ran Babel I have to run webpack or rollup?

Comment: You need to check bundler docs how to configure babel with particular bundler, btw you can check parcel, IMO the easiest bundler to setup